# onChange event not attaching to react TextArea

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add an onChange event listener after the page has already rendered.

The code seems to work, as after the timeout is over, the event fires once, but does not attach to the element.

```js
const myTimeout = setTimeout(addOnChange, 5000);

function addOnChange(){
  let comment_box = document.getElementsByClassName("text-area standard-focus wfFormControl form-control")[0];
  console.log(comment_box);
  comment_box.addEventListener("change", alert('works!!!'));
}
```

It finds the element, as it returns it in the console, but is not attached.

This is after the event fired:
[image]

Comment: That's not how React works. Why isn't the `onChange` on the text area when the component renders?

Comment: And `.addEventListener("change", alert('works!!!'))` is not how _that_ works, either. The second parameter needs to be a reference to a function, you _called_ a function instead.

Comment: @Andy Because I have no influence over the source code of this. I can just add some JS to the already rendered page. It is just that way, so I have to manipulate it afterwards. And I am no React developer sadly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem is that you're not passing a callback to `addEventListener` and a direct function call.

What about including a function on the second parameter of `addEventListener`:

```js
const myTimeout = setTimeout(addOnChange, 5000);

function addOnChange(){
  let comment_box = document.getElementsByClassName("text-area standard-focus wfFormControl form-control")[0];
  console.log(comment_box);
  comment_box.addEventListener("change", () => alert('works!!!'));
}
```

Comment: @MansNotHot it's still not how React works.

Comment: @Andy Thanks for pointing that out several times. I got an environment, and I got one thing to do. This thing has now succesfully been done. That's all I wanted. Altough I am now aware that "thats not how react works"

Comment: I mentioned it _twice_ because it's important. You may think this solves your problem but it just introduces a new one. @MansNotHot

Answer (score -1):

```js
const myTimeout = setTimeout(addOnChange, 5000);

function addOnChange(){
  let comment_box = document.querySelector(".text-area");
  console.log(comment_box);
  comment_box.addEventListener("change", function(){
  alert('works!!!');
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="comments-body">
<textarea class="text-area standard-focus wfFormControl form-control" rows="5" cols="20" area-label="Kommentar"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you adding all the class name while selecting element, It is not the good code. Instead use querySelector for better performance